# Solving systems of non-linear equations with two unknown coefficients a and b (scalars or vectors solutions ?)

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, equation, solver, equation-solving

I have systems of non-linear equations and I am looking for getting the two unknown "`a`" and "`b`" of the problem ( for the moment, I don't know if "`a`" and "`b`" could be only vectors or matrix solutions or maybe only scalars).

**The difficulty is that my equation is under matrix form (I mean that I have simply in theory only scalars "`a`" and "`b`" that multiplies matrices).**

I would like to use Matlab to solve this system of two non-linear equations (`a` and `b` are the unknown).

Here is the two independent equations : caution ! : "`FISH_sp`", "`FISH_xc`", "`eigenv_sp`" and "`eigenv_xc`" are known matrices.

`eigen_sp`, `eigen_xc` and `FISH_eigen_sum` are also scalar knonw.

I have coded the following system of 2 non-linear equations implemented in the following function (with `a` and `b` to find) :

```
myfun=@(a,b) [
% First equation
a^2*eye(7) + a*b*FISH_sp*FISH_xc'+a*b*FISH_xc*FISH_sp'+b^2*eye(7);
% Second equation
a*FISH_sp*eigenv_sp + b*FISH_eigen_sp*eigenv_xc + a*FISH_xc*eigenv_sp +...
b*FISH_xc*eigenv_xc - (eigenv_sp + eigenv_xc)*FISH_eigenv_sum];

% Solution of system of non linear equations
a0 = 0.5;
b0 = 0.5;
x0 = [ a0 b0 ];
y = fsolve(@(x)myfun(x(1),x(2)), x0)
```

But this gives me the following error :

```
Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in
compute_solving_Matricial_Equations>@(a,b)[a^2*eye(7)+a*b*FISH_sp*FISH_xc'+a*b*FISH_xc*FISH_sp'+b^2*eye(7);a*FISH_sp*eigenv_sp+b*FISH_eigen_sp*eigenv_xc+a*FISH_xc*eigenv_sp,+b*FISH_xc*eigenv_xc-(eigenv_sp+eigenv_xc)*FISH_eigenv_sum]

Error in compute_solving_Matricial_Equations>@(x)myfun(x(1),x(2))

Error in fsolve (line 230)
            fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});

Error in compute_solving_Matricial_Equations (line 55)
y = fsolve(@(x)myfun(x(1),x(2)), x0)

Caused by:
    Failure in initial objective function evaluation. FSOLVE cannot continue.
```

Anyone could see what's wrong to solve this system of 2 non linear functions described in the function `myfun` ?

Comment: Just a guess, but in the 1st eq. you have the term `b^2 Var(X,Y) ` that to me it seems a mistake, from the structure of the other terms I think it should be `b^2 Var(Y) `

Comment: @gboffi . Following another transcription of the problem, the system of 2 non linear equations has been modified (there is no more `Var` terms that are present)).

Comment: The first equation returns a 7x7 matrix if you use scalars and the second equation returns a scalar. How should this work? `a` and `b` must be scalars or vectors of length 7 otherwise, you run into a problem with `eye(7)`. Could you please clarify your question and create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (do not attach data with hyperlinks but provide to generate it, e.g. put all variables to `=1`)

Comment: @max . Sorry, you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65059072/matlab-solving-a-system-of-2-matricial-equations-building-each-element-of-ma a more accurate view of my problematic. Regards

Comment: @youpilat13 if you are no longer actively looking for an answer in this post but in the other one that you linked, would you please delete this post?

Comment: @Axel Jacobseen : this is the same problematic between both links, jut the second is more mature in explanations