# Matlab - Solving a system of 2 matricial equations : building each element of matrix solution

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication, symbolic-math, equation-solving

With Matlab, I have a matrix solution to find from 2 matricial equations (size matrix is 7x7). Here the 2 equations to solve with "`a`" and "`b`" are the unknow matrices and where `F1, F2, P1 and P2, D, D2, D` are known. Solving "a" and "b" would allow me to build a new matrix `P = a . P1 + b . P2` . (remark : `D` matrix is equal to : `D = a.a.D1 + b.b.D2` with D1and D2 diagonal matrices) :

1. `a.a + a.P1.b.P2^T + b.P2.a.P1^T + b.b - Id = 0` (equation 1)
2. `F1.a.P1 + F1.b.P2 + F2.a.P1 + F2.b.P2 − (a.P1 + b.P2).D = 0` (equation 2)

`Question 1)` Is there a solver in Matlab that would allow to directly find matrices "`a`" and "`b`" ?

`Question 2)` If there is no directly solving, I think that I have to solve each solution `a(i,j)` and `b(i,j`) by using a double loop on i and j indices and call fsolve in inner loop.

The problem is that I have to respect the order in matricial product and it is difficult to not make errors when I implement the code.

Here the 2 equations that I must solve on "`a`" and "`b`" unknown :

[image: equation 1] equation(1)

[image: equation 2] equation(2)

So I tried to implement the solving of each matrix element, i.e `a(i,j)` and `b(i,j)`

For this, I am using a symbolic array `x[7 7 2]` and did :

```
% eigenv_sp = P1
% eigenv_xc = P2
% FISH_sp = F1
% FISH_xc = F2
% FISH_eigen_sp = D1
% FISH_eigen_xc = D2

% Fisher matrices
F1 = FISH_sp;
F2 = FISH_xc;

% Transposed matrix
transp_eigenv_sp = eigenv_sp'
transp_eigenv_xc = eigenv_xc'

% Symbolic variables
x = sym([7 7 2]);
aP1 = sym([7 7]);
aP1T = sym([7 7]);
bP2 = sym([7 7]);
bP2T = sym([7 7]);
d1 = sym([7 7]);
d2 = sym([7 7]);
d = sym([7 7]);
ad1 = sym([7 7]);
bd2 = sym([7 7]);

for k=1:7
  for l=1:7
    aP1(k,l) = sum(x(k,1:7,1).*eigenv_sp(1:7,l));
    bP2(k,l) = sum(x(k,1:7,2).*eigenv_xc(1:7,l));

    aP1T(k,l) = sum(x(k,1:7,1).*transp_egeinv_sp(1:7,l));
    bP2T(k,l) = sum(x(k,1:7,2).*transp_egeinv_xc(1:7,l));

    a2(k,l) = sum(x(k,1:7,1).*x(1:7,l,1));
    b2(k,l) = sum(x(k,1:7,2).*x(1:7,l,2));

    d1(k,l) = FkSH_ekgen_sp(k,l);
    d2(k,l) = FkSH_ekgen_xc(k,l);
    d(k,l) = d1(k,l) + d2(k,l);

    ad1(k,l) = sum(x(k,1:7,1).d1(1:7,l));
    bd2(k,l) = sum(x(k,1:7,2).d2(1:7,l));
  end
end

% Function that represents `(a,b)(i,j)` unknown element represented by `(y(i,j,1),y(i,j,2))`
myfun=@(x,i,j) [

% First equation
sum(x(i,1:7,1).*x(1:7,j)) + sum(aP1(i,1:7).*bP2T(1:7,j)) + sum(bP2(i,1:7).*aP1T(1:7,j)) + sum(x(i,1:7).*x(1:7,2)) - eq(i,j);

% second equation
sum(F1(i,1:7).*aP1(1:7,j)) + sum(F1(i,1:7).*bP2(1:7,j)) + sum(F2(i,1:7).*aP1(1:7,j)) + sum(F2(i,1:7).*bP2(1:7,j)) - ...
sum(aP1(i,1:7).*ad1(1:7,j)) + sum(bP2(i,1:7).*ad1(1:7,j)) + sum(adP1(i,1:7).*dP2(1:7,j)) + sum(bP2(i,1:7).*dP2(1:7,j));
]

% Solution of system of non linear equations with loop
y = zeros(7, 7, 2);
for i=1:7
  for j=1:7
    a0 = 1e7;
    b0 = 1e7;
    x0 = [ a0 b0];
    y(i,j,:) = fsolve(@(x)myfun(x,i,j),x0)
    end
end
```

But at the execution, I have the following error :

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in sym/subsref (line 814)
            R_tilde = builtin('subsref',L_tilde,Idx);

Error in compute_solving_Matricial_Equations_dev (line 60)
    aP1(k,l) = sum(x(k,1:7,1).*eigenv_sp(1:7,l));
```

I don't understand where is the issue, I only iterate on index `1:7`, if someone could see what's wrong ?

### Update 1

I wonder if I have the right to use for a given index `i` the symbolic expression `x(1:7,i,1)` whereas this array is not known numerically but defined only from a symbolic point of view.

### Update 2

Maybe I have a clue.

If I do an expand of the symbolic array `x` (of size `(7,7,2)`), I get :

```
>> expand(sum(x(1,1:7).*x(1:7,1)))
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in sym/subsref (line 814)
            R_tilde = builtin('subsref',L_tilde,Idx);
```

So, the only thing to done I think is to explicitly write the 7x7 equations
with 7x7 = 49 couples unknown `x(i,j,1)` and `x(i,j,2)` which corresponds to `a(i,j)` and `b(i,j)` matrices.

### Update 3

I think the key point is to put into function `myfun` the 2 matrical equations but with taking into account of the 49 (7x7) couples `(a(i,j) and b(i,j))` unknown that I defined previously as symbolic variables with array `x[7 7 2]`.

And second point, **I must to "make understand" to `fsolve` that we are searching for each iteration (double loop on `(i,j)`) the value of `a(i,j)` and `b(i,j)` given the whole 49 equations**. Maybe it would be necessary to expand for example the expression of `x(i,1:7)` or `x(1:7,j)` in `myfun` function but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you use `.` between two matrices, does this mean "matrix multiplication"?

Comment: @Dev-iL . Yes, if I don't write the symbol `.*` and only `.`, this is a matricial product. But in the code, I think there is only the `.*` operation that I use.

Comment: Please see [this documentation page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html). If you want to do matrix multiplication (i.e. which follows the rules of algebra), you should use `*` in MATLAB. `.*` is for array multiplication (aka element-wise multiplication, Hadamard product). I haven't studied your code in detail, but this might be your problem.

Comment: @Dev-iL. You didn't understand, I have only used the character `.` in the images and text : this is only to not do confusions and highlight the fact that this is a matricial product. But this characer is not used in my code snippet, I only used `.*` to compute a single element `(i,j)` of the matricial product of 2 matrices.

Comment: `x = sym([7 7]);` does not defines a 7x7 symbolic matrix, but a symbolic 1x2 vector whose value is `[7 7]`. Maybe you want to use `x = sym('x', [7 7])`